# CfgNode parameters in Detectron2

Tags: python, detectron

I am new in object detection an I want to train an Neural Net in Detectron2. I had followed the tutorial and now, I want to know more about this tool. For setting up the model, this tool uses a CfgNode and I read the ReadTheDocs Detectron2's portal but there's not much enought about it. Someone can help me about which parameters I can set with CfgNode?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

All parameters that can be set in the `detectron2.config.CfgNode` object, including their description can be found [here](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/config.html#config-references).